# Location of highest values in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, indices, highest

Supose we have a `matrix` like this one:

```
# Set seed
  set.seed(12345)
# Generate data.frame  
  df <- matrix(sample(1:100,100), nrow = 10)
```

I would like to **get the row and column where the first `n` highest values are placed**.

I  know that using `which(df == max(df), arr.ind=TRUE)` I get what I want but only for the highest value.

Let's suppose we want the location of the 5 highest values in the matrix. Based on the previous answer, I tried `which(aux %in% sort(df, decreasing=T)[1:5], arr.ind = TRUE)` but it did not work.

I also know that using  `order(df, decreasing=T)` and modulating the results I can get rows and columns I am looking for. Nevertheless, I think it should be a fastest way to get it.

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Quick and dirty solution, find everything that's greater or equal to the lowest of your top 5 values: `which(df >= min(sort(df, decreasing=T)[1:5]), arr.ind=TRUE)`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `match()` and `arrayInd()`:

```
vals <- head(sort(df, decreasing = TRUE), 5)

cbind(vals, arrayInd(match(vals, df), dim(df), useNames = TRUE))

     vals row col
[1,]  100   8   3
[2,]   99   9   9
[3,]   98   4   8
[4,]   97   7   9
[5,]   96   3   2
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `quantile`.

```
which(df >= quantile(df, 1 - 5/length(df)), arr.ind=TRUE)
#     row col
#[1,]   3   2
#[2,]   8   3
#[3,]   4   8
#[4,]   7   9
#[5,]   9   9
```

In case there are identical values the result need not to be 5.

```
i <- which(df >= quantile(df, 1 - 5/length(df)))
arrayInd(i[order(df[i], decreasing = TRUE)][1:5], dim(df))
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    8    3
#[2,]    9    9
#[3,]    4    8
#[4,]    7    9
#[5,]    3    2
```

Maybe using tdigest can speed up the search of the quantile.

Or use the `head` of `order` and use `%%` and `%/%`.

```
. <- head(order(df, decreasing = TRUE), 5) - 1
cbind(. %% dim(df)[[1]], . %/% dim(df)[[1]]) + 1
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    8    3
#[2,]    9    9
#[3,]    4    8
#[4,]    7    9
#[5,]    3    2
```

Or transform the indices with `arrayInd`.

```
arrayInd(head(order(df, decreasing = TRUE), 5), dim(df))
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    8    3
#[2,]    9    9
#[3,]    4    8
#[4,]    7    9
#[5,]    3    2
```

Maybe using some external library can help to speed it up like `collapse::radixorderv`.

```
. <- head(collapse::radixorderv(df, decreasing = TRUE), 5) - 1
cbind(. %% dim(df)[[1]], . %/% dim(df)[[1]]) + 1
```

Comment: The `quantile` option is cool! upvoted for that!

Answer (score 2):

Your method works. Its just that should convert to a 2 dimensional array before using `which`:

```
which(array(df %in% tail(sort(df), 5), dim(df)), TRUE)

     row col
[1,]   3   2
[2,]   8   3
[3,]   4   8
[4,]   7   9
[5,]   9   9
```

Comment: So, what I did returned a vector and I had to transform it into a `martix` or an `array` in order to be able to use `which`

Answer (score 1):

A base R option with `expand.grid` + `order`

```
> expand.grid(lapply(dim(df), seq))[order(-c(df)), ][1:5, ]
   Var1 Var2
28    8    3
89    9    9
74    4    8
87    7    9
13    3    2
```

---

Here is a `data.table` version, where both the values and indices are presented

```
library(data.table)

setorder(
    data.table(
        val = c(df),
        CJ(
            col = 1:ncol(df),
            row = 1:nrow(df)
        )
    ), -val
)[1:5]
```

which gives

```
   val col row
1: 100   3   8
2:  99   9   9
3:  98   8   4
4:  97   9   7
5:  96   2   3
```